# Mudar o Javascript Window.Open para abrir um Iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

Estou com esse javascript, e quero fazer que ao invés de abrir uma nova janela, ele abra um iframe.

---

```
 window.self.name = "emanager";
 function MostraBarra(){
 if (document.incluir.balancete_arquivo.value != ""){
 window.open('<%=BARRASTATUS%>','upload','width=400,height=150');
 }
 return true;
 }
```

Comment: A pergunta não está clara porque um iframe pode ser inserido em qualquer lugar da página.

Comment: Então, não importa o lugar dá página, eu quero somente que ao invés dessa chamada window.open('<%=BARRASTATUS%>','upload','width=400,height=150');, seja puxando um iframe, assim talvez upload.html

Comment: Mas um iframe é uma tag HTML que deve ser inserida na página. Onde?!

Comment: Na mesma página da chamada o script.

Comment: Isso eu sei amigo. Mas onde na página? No ínício, no final, oculto, tipo uma modal, no meio, após algum elemento específico etc etc... é isso que tá vago na pergunta.

Comment: Isso, o iframe será colocado no final da página, quando for clicado o botão ele irá aparecer.

Comment: Bem-vindo Samuel Neto, considere marcar uma resposta que melhor lhe atendeu como aceita. Veja como em https://i.stack.imgur.com/evLUR.png e porque em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um iframe não é algo que "se abra" da mesma forma que se abre uma janela. Ele é uma tag HTML que você insere na página e carrega uma outra página.

O que você pode fazer é inserir a tag onde você deseja na página sem especificar uma URL e de forma oculta com `display: none;`:

```
<iframe style="display: none;"></iframe>
```

Na função você altera a visibilidade do `iframe` e define um `src` que será a página a ser carregada:

```
function MostraBarra(){
   if (document.incluir.balancete_arquivo.value != ""){
//      window.open('<%=BARRASTATUS%>','upload','width=400,height=150');
      var iframe = document.querySelector("iframe"); // seleciona o iframe pela tag
      iframe.style.display = "block"; // altera o display tornado-o visível
      iframe.src = "<%=BARRASTATUS%>"; // carrega uma página no iframe
   }
   return true;
}
```

Aí você pode definir os estilos do `iframe` via CSS da forma que quiser:

```
iframe{
   width: 100%;
   height: 400px;
   border: none;
}
```

Demais propriedades do `iframe` você pode verificar na **[documentação do MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)**.

Comment: Show, muito obrigado sam!!!

Comment: Seja bem-vindo! Se já conhece o funcionamento do site, deve marcar ✔️ apenas na melhor resposta que achou.

Answer (score 0):

Você só precisa fazer um

```
if (document.incluir.balancete_arquivo.value != ""){
    var frame = document.getElementById('iframe') //Id do seu iframe aqui
    frame.src = '<%=BARRASTATUS%>'; // Considerando que BARRASTATUS 
                                   //  tenha o url que vai ser passado pro frame
}
```

Tendo isso, o iframe já vai carregar a outra tela; Agora, você precisa definir o tamanho, visibilidade, etc...

Answer (score 0):

**Javascript**

```
function prepareFrame() {
    if (document.incluir.balancete_arquivo.value != ""){
       var ifrm = document.createElement("iframe");
       ifrm.setAttribute("src", "<%=BARRASTATUS%>");
       ifrm.style.width = "400px";
       ifrm.style.height = "150px";
       document.body.appendChild(ifrm);
   }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" onclick="prepareFrame()">Criar iframe</button>
```

### Para criar o iframe no local exato:

```
function prepareFrame() {
    var ifrm = document.createElement("iframe"); 
    ifrm.setAttribute("src", "radioalfa2233.htm");
    ifrm.style.width = "400px";
    ifrm.style.height = "150px";
    //o iframe será criado antes da div de id = divqq
    var divReferencia = document.getElementById("divqq");
    // adiciona o novo elemento criado e seu conteúdo ao DOM
    document.body.insertBefore(ifrm, divReferencia);
}
```

e no HTML insira essa div `<div id="divqq"></div>` no local exato onde o iframe deva ser criado

**Caso queira esconder o button após clicado**

acrescente essa linha dentro do `if` no script

`document.getElementById('bt').style.display = 'none';`

e o id no button `<button id="bt"....`

- A função `createElement()` criará um elemento HTML para ser inserido em um documento HTML
- Aparentemente, a função `createElement()` não surte efeito algum, precisamos aplicar o método `appendChild()` para que o elemento seja, efetivamente, inserido ao documento HTML e fique visível ao usuário.

Comment: Muito bom, obrigado!!!!